# How to build zeromq without sodium on Visual Studio Community

Tags: visual-studio, build, zeromq

I would like to build zeromq on Visual Studio Community without libsodium.
Were and how could I disable it?

Comment: Are you building a .NET app? If so, then you should consider NetMQ, which is a native C# implemented version of ZeroMQ.

Comment: I am trying to build C++ app, first example client and server if possible.

Comment: Alright, then that comment is of no use. Carry on :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate the libzmq solution using CMake. You should be able to tell CMake to disable libsodium by invoking it like this: `cmake -DWITH_TWEETNACL=0 ..`